# Invoice query per 2 weeks. The best practice

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on a invoice system for a application of mine. I want to invoice the users every 2 weeks. There is a cronjob every week with the check if the user gets an invoice. But it give me some bugs, because it has been a new year and the system gives someone a invoice even when they have got them a week ago.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   user 
WHERE  DAY(registered) = DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK))
 OR    DAY(registered) = DAY(NOW()) AND registered != CURRENT_DATE()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us some sample data in your table and expected output? please. BTW is it MYSQL?

Comment: what is 'registered' and how do you know if you sent an invoice 1 week ago? (to avoid sending weekly)

Comment: note- your 'or' clause needs parens around it - otherwise it will be read as two clauses

Comment: @ethrbunny the collumn registered is a TIMESTAMP in the Sql table.

Comment: Another approach would be use epoch time for your comparisons. Then wrapping year boundaries would be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this- (code is tested) [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd506/1)

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE registered > CURRENT_DATE() AND 
MOD((FLOOR( DATEDIFF( now( ) , `registered` ))),14) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `day` function in MySQL returns the day of month.  You will clearly have problems with your query when the time period spans month boundaries.

I think you want logic of this form:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   user 
WHERE  registered >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)) and
       registered < curdate()
```

(Or `<=` if you want the current date to be invoiced.)

I do not know what this is doing:

```
 OR    DAY(registered) = DAY(NOW()) AND registered != CURRENT_DATE()
```

If the day of the month is the same for registered and now(), then registered should be the current date.  The only difference between `now()` and `curdate()` is that the former includes the time stamp.  I would also say that it is bad practice to mix three different ways of getting the same date in the same query, even if they are equivalent.